# React + Flux: Action triggers synchronous ajax requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I am building a survey style app using React + Flux. When a user submits an answer I fire off an action that triggers an ajax request to save the answer in the database (ajax request #1). I then need to do an ajax request to get the next question (ajax request #2).

Request #2 depends on the data that #1 writes to the database. I'd like to avoid returning the next question when creating the answer. Any suggestions on where/how best to trigger #2 so that we can be assured #1 has finished?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you want to avoid returning the next question when creating the answer?

Comment: Mainly just to make each API endpoint be a single concern. This is probably the route I will end up taking though unless anything better comes along.

Answer (score 0):

Within your Ajax success function, you can let the AppDispatcher announce something like `QUESTION_ANSWERED`, passing the question number.

A store can now listen for that event, set the just-answered question, and emit its `CHANGE` event.

Your survey component can then listen for this event and, when it receives a notification from the store, create a new action to get the next question.

That gets you separate endpoints (which I agree with you is preferable).

HTH

Comment: would do you that using actions?